# PHP If statement on select elemnet created with array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, select

I'm new to PHP and encountering an issue I am unable to resolve.

say we have this:

```
<select name="car">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and my php is:

```
if (isset($_POST['car']) && $_POST['car'] == "Audi") {
    echo 'Please select a better car.';
}
```

this works.
However,I made a generated select off an array:

```
<select name="q1" value="<?php echo $q1 ?>">
        <?php foreach ($toppings as $key => $value) { ?>
            <option <?php if ($q1 == $key) { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

and then I wrote this php code as follows:

```
<?php
$toppings = array(1 => "Anchovie", 2 => "Tomato", 3 => "Corn", 4 => "Bulgarian", 5 => "Pineapple", 6 => "Pepperoni", 7 => "Green Olives", 8 => "Ground Beef", 9 => "Red Peppers", 10 => "Tuna", 11 => "Cheese");

if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $_POST['q1'] == "Cheese") {
    echo 'you selected cheese!.';
}
?>
```

This does not work and I am unable to figure why on my own.
Please help,
thank you.

Comment: `selected="selected"` not selected="true" and your post value is key of array not the the value, so you can't compare `$_POST['q1']` with `Cheese`, You need to compare it with `11`.

Comment: what is the value of `$q1` by default

Comment: @Narayan `$q1` is not any variable?

Comment: @FrayneKonok oh then  he is trying to check the post value q1 here `($q1 == $key)`

Comment: Thanks guys...glad to finally understand what i did wrong :)
I am gonna compare to key insted as you said. as you said

Comment: You did some more mistakes as i mentioned in my answer, hope you will check these too...

Comment: will do @frank konok. ty :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not sure, try to echo what exactly is in `$_POST['q1']`.

In `$_POST['q1']`, there will be value attribute of your `<option>`, not its text content. When generating the `<select>`, you use $key for value attribute, therefore you'll have there '1', '2', '3' instead of 'Anchovie', 'Tomato' atd.

So, either change `if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $_POST['q1'] == "Cheese")` to `if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $_POST['q1'] == "11")` or change `value="<?php echo $key ?>"` to `value="<?php echo $value ?>"`.

Comment: Glad to help you. Please don't forget to mark the question as answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the dropdown will return the numbers which is exists in the array as key..you can get the values from array.Do like below:

```
<?php
$toppings = array(1 => "Anchovie", 2 => "Tomato", 3 => "Corn", 4 => "Bulgarian", 5 => "Pineapple", 6 => "Pepperoni", 7 => "Green Olives", 8 => "Ground Beef", 9 => "Red Peppers", 10 => "Tuna", 11 => "Cheese");

if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $toppings[$_POST['q1']] == "Cheese") {
    echo 'you selected cheese!.';
}
?>
```

Or change the option value to $value.

```
<select name="q1" value="<?php echo $q1 ?>">
        <?php foreach ($toppings as $key => $value) { ?>
            <option <?php if ($q1 == $key) { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
        <?php } ?>

    </select>
if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $_POST['q1'] == "Cheese") {
        echo 'you selected cheese!.';
    }
```

Comment: What is it `$toppings($_POST['q1'])`??

Comment: he is getting the key value ...the key values are there in $toppings..need to compare key value

Comment: So you need to use `[]` not `()`

Answer (score 0):

You do several mistakes in your question-

1. `if (isset($_POST['car']) && $_POST['car'] == "Audi") {` You are comparing `Audi` which is not in a value for the selectbox, It should be `audi`.
2. `selected="true"` which is not a valid syntax, You need to use `selected='selected'`
3. Comparing `$_POST['q1'] == "Cheese"` where your posted value is the array key, So you need to change `"Cheese"` to that array key or use the selectbox value of array value.

Answer (score 0):

Ty all I see my error I'll compare to key instead of value :)

```
if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $_POST['q1'] == "11") {
    echo 'you selected cheese!.';
}
```

<3!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare `$_POST['q1']` with `'11'`. You will get value of selected option in `$_POST['q1']` not selected option text.
So your working code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $_POST['q1'] == "11") {
```

Just change it, It will work.